# Плавное появление линии при скролле страницы

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css3, анимация

Как при скролле сайта, когда дойду до нужного блока, реализовать плавное из центра до левого и правого края появление линии?

Comment: _"... делаю сайт."_ Это точно? А то что-то кода не видно...

Comment: @UModeL, вы забыли про чертоги разума

Comment: посмотрите в сети `hover.css` - https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ - тут вроде как есть и нужный вам эффект - зайдите (когда скачаете) внутрь стилей и посмотрите как устроен нужный вам

Comment: Нету кода для линии, просто нужно чтоб с центра страницы до краев плавно линия выходило.

Comment: @Вадим: _"Нету кода для линии..."_ Но, код, куда собираетесь вставлять линию есть? Приложите к вопросу. И, да, одним лишь CSS обойтись не получится - отслеживать скролл только через JS, поэтому добавьте метку в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример, когда элемент (ваш блок) находится ровно по центру экрана, то ему добавляется еще один класс, для которого мы прописываем правило `@keyframes` и устанавливаем ключевые кадры. Но это импровизация, потому что из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно, в какой момент должна происходить анимация, а также каким элементом должна являться эта линия.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.block').each(function() {
      var self = $(this),
        height = self.offset().top + self.height() / 2 - windowHeight / 2;
      if ($(document).scrollTop() >= height) {
        self.addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.page {
  position: relative;
  height: 3000px;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: chocolate;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.active:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  animation: 3s linear animate;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    left: 50%;
    width: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <h1>Крутим вниз</h1>
  <div class="block">Какой-то блок</div>
</div>
```